# Django and django oscar

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, django-oscar

Location of django:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc
```

Location of django oscar:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/__init__.pyc
```

My static files are not getting served properly. Above is my production setting. On my local machine, the locations are:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oscar/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc
```

Could this be a possible reason for above problem?

Comment: If you could explain more about your setup, it would be easier to help you. How are you serving your Django project? Are you just running `manage.py runserver` or have you setup something like an Nginx reverse proxy?

Comment: I'm using Digital Ocean's service. It has gunicorn and nginx pre installed and pre-configured for my django app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Oscar ships](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/tree/master/oscar/static/oscar) its own set of static files in `oscar/static/oscar` When you deploy your site, you should run `manage.py collectstatic` so these files are also [collected](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) in your `STATIC_ROOT`

On DigitalOcean's Django app, your Nginx configuration is located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django` You may need to update the following section to point to the location of your `STATIC_ROOT`

```
    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Now it has got another problem though. When I set debug=False, the site gives internal error. I have put the ip address and domain name in the list of allowed hosts.

Comment: Also, all the images in my 'media' folder specified by "MEDIA_ROOT" returns a 403 forbidden error. This folder contains dynamically created and some static images too.